# Running CVS in console upsets BZR by changing output encoding

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, cvs, bazaar

I am using both cvs and bzr for versioning and prefer running both in a powershell console.
But when I run cvs, it changes the console encoding, which makes bzr throw error messages.
I tried setting $OutputEncoding to UTF-8 in my PSProfile and then bzr seems happy... until I run cvs, then bzr starts to complain again - even though $OutputEncoding is the same!?

Is there any way to get the two to work in the same console?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt variables set.
PS W:\> [Console]::OutputEncoding.EncodingName
Western European (DOS)
PS W:\> bzr st
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "W:/".
PS W:\> [Console]::OutputEncoding.EncodingName
Western European (DOS)
PS W:\> cvs up
cvs update: No CVSROOT specified!  Please use the `-d' option
cvs [update aborted]: or set the CVSROOT environment variable.
PS W:\> [Console]::OutputEncoding.EncodingName
Unicode (UTF-8)
PS W:\> bzr st
bzr: warning: unknown terminal encoding cp65001.
  Using encoding cp1252 instead.
bzr: warning: unknown terminal encoding cp65001.
  Using encoding cp1252 instead.
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "W:/".
PS W:\>
```

Example with forcing OutputEncoding to UTF8 in the PSProfile.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt variables set.
PS W:\> $OutputEncoding


BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001



PS W:\> bzr st
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "W:/".
PS W:\> cvs up
cvs update: No CVSROOT specified!  Please use the `-d' option
cvs [update aborted]: or set the CVSROOT environment variable.
PS W:\> $OutputEncoding


BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001



PS W:\> bzr st
bzr: warning: unknown terminal encoding cp65001.
  Using encoding cp1252 instead.
bzr: warning: unknown terminal encoding cp65001.
  Using encoding cp1252 instead.
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "W:/".
PS W:\>
```

Comment: That warning is harmless in your case.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to provide a [output-encoding](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/user-reference/configuration-help.html#output-encoding) option in your bazaar.conf.

The cp65001 was added to python 3.3 ([bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue13216).) So this would be fixed if bzr ports to py3k (I'm hoping...)

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the output_encoding option to my config, and now the error message only occurs once for each invocation of bzr (regardless of the value of the option, as long as it's a valid encoding identifier). So the option doesn't completely override the terminal setting, it seems. But still - problem half solved? :)